# Pass calculated values by inherited classes to main class

Tags: java

So in my main function I got a class named `Figure`

Circle and Rectangle extend class Figure.
Square extends class Rectangle.

Now I have to print the values from created objects. I think I am approaching this in wrong way. How can I pass the values to the `print` function that have been created by other classes?

```java
public class Figure { 
  private double area;
  private double perimeter;
  private String name;

  public Figure() { 
    this.area = 0.0;
    this.perimeter = 0.0;
    this.name = "";
  }

   public void print() {
        System.out.println(this.area + this.perimeter + this.name);
    }
     public static void main(String args[]) {

      Figure[] figureList = new Figure[5];
        figureList[0] = new Circle(5);
        figureList[1] = new Square(5);
        figureList[2] = new Rectangle(5, 9);

        for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
         System.out.println(figureList[i].print()); // wont print anything
        }
     }
}
```

```java
public class Circle extends Figure {
    private double radius;
    
    public Circle(double a) {
        this.radius= a;

        this.calcPerimeter();
        this.calcArea();
    }

    public double calcPerimeter(){
        return 2*(Math.PI*this.radius);
    }
    public double calcArea(){
        return Math.PI*(this.radius*this.radius);
    }
    public void increase(int a){
        this.radius*=a;
        this.calcArea();
    }

    
}
```

Should I not be using `return` in the calcPerimeter and calcArea methods? Because I need to pass this somehow to Figure class. Also I have same as above class for rectangle.

And this class that extends rectangle.

```java
public class Square extends Rectangle {
    private double sideA;

    public Square(double a) {
        this.sideA = a;

        this.calcPerimeter();
        this.calcArea();
    }

    public double calcArea() {
        return (this.sideA*this.sideA);
    }

    public double calcPerimeter() {
        return 4*this.sideA;
    }
}
```

Can someone advice me how to do it properly, I just started my journey with Java and Im practicing on objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you have made all 3 members of Figure class as `private`, so if you want the base classes to update them, then make them `protected`, and use `super.area, super.perimeter,` etc. to update them.

Yes you dont need to `return` but update parent's values using the super keyword.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my issue. Also when should I use `private` for variables?